# Is there a difference in the capacity of textarea elements between Firefox and Chrome-based browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, brave

I was breaking the undo/redo chain in textarea elements and handling it manually to make it persist across sessions, and found that it worked well in Firefox but not in anything chrome.

To make sure it wasn't my JS code, I made a local page with only a textarea and pasted about 2MB of text in it (as a sort of upper limit test) and, Firefox handles it fine but Chrome is terrible. All the text is pasted in the elements, but Chrome is extremely slow to respond to key strokes; the scroll jumps around to move the cursor position to the first line of the visible content when first start typing; the built-in undo/redo is very slow; and sometimes, when scrolling, the textarea appears empty. This does not happen in Firefox.

I turned off spell checker and translation but it made no difference.

Is this expected or is there a browser setting or something that can be done in JS to make chrome handle textarea elements better? I realize that 2MB is a lot of text for a user to type in a single container, but didn't expect there to be such a difference between browsers and thought chrome-based browsers were the quickest.

Thank you.